# MaterializeCSS Modal won't open, Dropdown in a Form, and Tab Groups href

Tags: html, materialize

```
 <div class="row center">
        <button data-target="modal1" class="btn modal-trigger">Modal</button>
      </div>
<!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is what the code was from the website. I have tried every possible change to fix the error than nothing happens when the modal is clicked on.

also had more questions.
How can i get tabs (still in materializecss) to redirect to another page on click?

`<li class="tab col s3"><a href="/student/login/">Login</a></li>`

this doesn't seem to work

PS the normal format for a tab is

```
<li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test1">Register</a></li>
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: dropdown fixed, just used a select div

```
 <div class="input-field col s12">
   <select>
     <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
     <option value="1">Option 1</option>
     <option value="2">Option 2</option>
     <option value="3">Option 3</option>
   </select>
   <label>Materialize Select</label>
 </div>
```

Then, in a js file, call

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('select').material_select();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try giving the button an id

```
<button id="trigger" data-target="modal1" class="btn modal-trigger">Modal</button>
```

and add a click event to it in your jquery

```
$('#trigger').click(function(e){
    $('#modal1').openModal();
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////This is my code
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function($) {
            // This command is used to initialize some elements and make them work properly
            $.material.init();
        });
    </script>

@Ik404